# EM tensor dual in spherical coordinates?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, special-relativity

I'm trying to find the dual of the EM tensor in spherical coordinates.
Defining the metric of the sign (-+++)
$$ ds^2 = - dt^2 + dr^2 + r^2 (d\theta^2 + \sin(\theta)^2d\phi^2) $$
I identified the EM tensor as
$$F^{\mu\nu} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \text{Er} & \frac{\text{E$\theta $}}{r} &
   \frac{\text{E$\phi $} \csc (\theta )}{r} \\
 -\text{Er} & 0 & \frac{\text{B$\phi $}}{r} &
   -\frac{\text{B$\theta $} \csc (\theta )}{r}
   \\
 -\frac{\text{E$\theta $}}{r} &
   -\frac{\text{B$\phi $}}{r} & 0 &
   \frac{\text{Br} \csc (\theta )}{r^2} \\
 -\frac{\text{E$\phi $} \csc (\theta )}{r} &
   \frac{\text{B$\theta $} \csc (\theta )}{r} &
   -\frac{\text{Br} \csc (\theta )}{r^2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$
where $\csc(\theta) = 1/\sin(\theta)$.
Now finding the dual of the tensor as
$$\star F^{\mu\nu} = \epsilon^{abcd} F_{cd} = \epsilon^{abcd} g_{ij} g_{kl}F^{jl}   $$
,where $\epsilon$ is the levi-civita symbol.
I get
$$\star F^{\mu\nu}=  \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & r^2 \sin (\theta ) \text{Br}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) & r \sin (\theta ) \text{B$\theta $}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) & r
   \text{B$\phi $}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) \\
 -r^2 \sin (\theta ) \text{Br}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) & 0 & -r \sin (\theta ) \text{E$\phi $}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) & r
   \text{E$\theta $}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) \\
 -r \sin (\theta ) \text{B$\theta $}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) & r \sin (\theta ) \text{E$\phi $}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) & 0 &
   -\text{Er}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) \\
 -r \text{B$\phi $}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) & -r \text{E$\theta $}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) & \text{Er}(t,r,\theta ,\phi ) & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
But I was told that this isn't ok, where was my mistake?
Is this definition of dual right even in non Minkowski metric?

Comment: When I tried to replicate the question in cylindrical coordinates, my $\star F^{\mu\nu}$ differed by a factor of $1/\sqrt{-g}$ from the "right one".

Comment: Your metric has an error: it should be $\sin^2 \theta $ not $\sin \theta$

Comment: @Eletie I think the word "typo" is better than "error". When people writes equation with mathjax, they become blind so do I.

Comment: yes a typo, I edited it, thank you.

Comment: $\epsilon$ should be Levi-Civita tensor, rather than symbol, that's where $\sqrt{-g}$ is coming from

Comment: $\epsilon^{abcd}=\varepsilon^{abcd}/\sqrt{-g}$ and $\epsilon_{abcd}=\sqrt{-g}\varepsilon_{abcd}$, where $\varepsilon$ is the symbol.

Comment: yes you are right, I have confused myself. Thank you very much!